# jquery click happens too fast to refresh results from database?

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I'm making a simple shoutbox and when someone posts a message the message is added to the database just fine. I made a refresh button which populates all the messages in the text area. 
I am trying to call the .click() on the refresh button after the person enters the message but I think it happens too fast and doesn't catch the new message in the database. I works if I add an alert to give it more time. Is there a better way?

```
$("#shoutBtn").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $.post("includes/shoutBoxPost.php", {"message": $("#messageBox").val(),
                                     "name": $("#userNameWelcome").html()});
   $("#messageBox").val("");
   $("#shoutRefresh").click();  
});
```

I changed my code to the long hand ajax way and it works thanks for answers folks

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"message": $("#messageBox").val(),
            "name": $("#userNameWelcome").html()},
      url : 'includes/shoutBoxPost.php',
      success : function(data) {
          $("#messageBox").val("");
          $("#shoutRefresh").click();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Glad you have fixed it, ya ajax is async

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation for [jQuery .post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).  You can define a success callback that will only fire once the post request successfully returns.

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )

$.post("includes/shoutBoxPost.php", 
    {"message": $("#messageBox").val(), "name": $("#userNameWelcome").html()},
    function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        $("#shoutRefresh").click();
    }
);
```

Comment: @David I usually avoid using the shortcut ajax functions and just go with the `$.ajax` approach, figured I'd stick with what the OP is using

Answer (score 1):

you can add call back function to your post

```
$.post( "includes/shoutBoxPost.php",{"message": $("#messageBox").val(), "name": $("#userNameWelcome").html()})
.done(function( data ) {
$("#messageBox").val("");
$("#shoutRefresh").click();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for your post to finish and send a success message back (via JSON), then do the refresh action.